# how to make login data available in certain View Controller when login using Google using Firebase Auth?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have followed all the steps provided from official documentation in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin#swift_5) to implement google sign in for iOS.

so I have LoginVC that has google sign in button, when that button is clicked, then it will show login page created by google. here is the IB action for google login button

```
@IBAction func googleButtonDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
```

after the user login successfully, it will back to LoginVC from Google Login Page. I want to perform another action in `LoginVC` after the user login successfully.

the problem is, when the user login successfully, it will trigger a method below in App Delegate. but I need `GIDGooleUser` data in `LoginVC` not in `appdelegate`

```
extension AppDelegate : GIDSignInDelegate {


    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

       // this method called after the user login successfully
       // i need user: GIDGoogleUser in my LoginVC

    }


}
```

I need that `GIDGooleUser` to get `credential` , and then that `credential` will be used to sign in to get `AuthDataResult` and `FirebaseUser`

so how to make notify my LoginVC when login is successful and bring `GIDGooleUser` to my `LoginVC` ?

Comment: Pass the data by NSNotification to your controller

Answer (score 0):

Sample code:
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
            print("(error.localizedDescription)")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: googleSignInNotification), object: nil, userInfo: ["result" : false])
        } else {
            let userId:String = user.userID
            let idToken:String = user.authentication.idToken
            let fullName:String = user.profile.name
            let givenName:String = user.profile.givenName
            let familyName:String = user.profile.familyName
            let email:String = user.profile.email
      let imageUrl:String=user.profile.imageURL(withDimension:100).absoluteString
       let userDetailsDictionary: [String:String] = ["FirstName": givenName, "LastName": familyName, "Gender": "", "DOB" : "", "GoogleID": userId, "FacebookID": "", "Email": email,"ProfilePicUrl" : imageUrl]

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: googleSignInNotification), object: nil, userInfo: ["result" : true])
        }

```
}
```